# Spring and @JsonView with multiple identifiers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Spring supports `@JsonView` since version 4.1.

Annotating a Spring contoller's (annotated with `@RestController`) method with `@JsonView` that has multiple identifiers I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @JsonView only supported for request body advice with exactly 1 class argument: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@a566e37e
```

Apparently according to the `JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice`'s [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice.html) the following is true:

> Note that despite @JsonView allowing for more than one class to be
>   specified, the use for a response body advice is only supported with
>   exactly one class argument. Consider the use of a composite interface.

Likewise when annotating a controller's method argument (annotated with `@RequestBody`) also with `@JsonView` that has multiple identifiers; according to the `JsonViewRequestBodyAdvice`'s [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/JsonViewRequestBodyAdvice.html):

> Note that despite @JsonView allowing for more than one class to be
>   specified, the use for a request body advice is only supported with
>   exactly one class argument. Consider the use of a composite interface.

Does anybody knows if a fix is planned? My current Spring version is 4.2.4.

This would be extremely useful creating json views for public, private (extending public), summary and detailed (extending summary) views and then combining them in the controller methods!

Answer (score 26):

As explained in [Jackson JsonView documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews), "only single active view per serialization; but due to inheritance of Views, can combine Views via aggregation".

Concretely, if you want to use both `Foo` and `Bar` JsonViews, define a `FooBar` interface that combine them as following:

```
interface Foo {}

interface Bar {}

interface FooBar extends Foo, Bar {}
```

You can then annotate your fields with `@JsonView(Foo.class)` or `@JsonView(Bar.class)` and use `@JsonView(FooBar.class)` at controller level.

Comment: Thank you Sebastien for your comments but the question is you we can use inheritance (and not aggregation).

Comment: Not sure to understand, could you please give me more details about your use case?